# Change the video source and displays the first frame, but i don't want this

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I have a list of the MediaElement in WPF and I have a button that allows me to change video. When I click the button, check the new video source to the video and I want to run right away, so I do video.play (). In addition, I want the video to start in a certain position and then change video.position.
However, it happens that for a moment, it shows the first frame of the video and then the video runs at the position indicated.

How do I prevent see the first frame?

Thank you all!

Comment: This is an old post (from 2008) but it seems it was by design http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/347d3525-b891-4233-a694-4f4743f88be0/using-mediaelement-and-position-property-problem-first-frame-is-shown-which-should-not-occure However, there may be a way round it now but it seems that the default behaviour is the same.

Comment: Thanks for response... So there isn't a way to resolve the bug?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a look at the issue. Hopefully someone else has figured out a way :)